# Jquery caching CSS

Tags: jquery, css, caching

I have a small script that filters results from multiple select options.  The script simply changes the CSS (background-image) to highlight the result of the filter.

Trouble is if the visitor wants to play and goes click click click CLEAR click click click CLEAR etc etc, the highlighting gets confused and results are incorrect. If I do a page reload, all back to normal again.  I don't know if the CSS is being cached or the Jquery is getting cached?

Below is a snippet of the CSS Filter

```
if (a == 1 && b == 0) {
        $("a#tourer").css('background-position', '0 bottom');
    } else {
        $("a#tourer").css({
            "background-position": "0 top",
            opacity: "0.3",
            filter: "alpha(opacity=30)"
        });
    }
```

and below is the action on clicking the form "Clear results" button

```
    $("#reset").click(function() {
    $("#formreset")[0].reset();
    j = 1;
    $('.select_list').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('select_list select_list' + j);
        j++;
    });
    $('.model_row').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).find('a').removeAttr("style");
    });
    return false;
});
```

.select_list are in the form itself, and .model_row are outside the form as a style for DIV tags containing the background image / result.

I could just simply tell the script to reload the page, but would prefer not to. More professional to reset the form...

All the code works as expected, apart from the caching? problem.

Cheers

Comment: why would you be adding the class `select_list` to an element that is found by using that same class? Seems like a logic problem. Please create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem. Also have you inspected the live html in browser console to see that classes and inline style are what you expect them to be?

Comment: Thx charlietfl - When I view the live HTML after "Clear", all inline CSS is correct and accounted for.  What is happening is that inline CSS is being applied when I reselect options after "Clear" which shouldn't be there!!  The form containing .select_list is always displaying the correct inline CSS regardless of clearing or not...

Comment: create a demo, very hard to see what your problem is without being able to inspect live code. Not sure either what relationship is between ID and class above.

Comment: not sure what I should be doing but playing with reset seems to work fine for me. That code is far more complicated than it needs to be though. No need for unique classes for each and every element

Comment: can't chat with you without 20 rep points